# Difference between yare and nimble?

Tags: differences, synonyms, comparisons

Based on the definitions, yare<sup>1</sup> seems like a subset of nimble, that is to say, anytime you could use yare<sup>1</sup>, you could use nimble<sup>1</sup> instead, but nimble<sup>2</sup> and nimble<sup>3</sup> are clearly (I think) distinct from yare<sup>1</sup>. So when would you ever use yare<sup>1</sup> specifically over nimble<sup>1</sup>?

Also, I think what is adding to my confusion is that the "archaic" yare<sup>3</sup> definition includes nimble as a synonym.

I am of course not conidering yare<sup>2</sup> (or really even yare<sup>3</sup>) in the context of this question, just yare<sup>1</sup>.

---

From dictionary.com:

> **Yare**
>
> 1. quick; agile; lively.
> 2. (of a ship) quick to the helm; easily handled or maneuvered.
> 3. *Archaic.* 
>    ready; prepared.
>    nimble; quick.
>
> http://www.dictionary.com/browse/yare

> **Nimble**
>
> 1. quick and light in movement; moving with ease; agile; active; rapid:
>    *nimble feet.*
> 2. quick to understand, think, devise, etc.:
>    *a nimble mind.*
> 3. cleverly contrived:
>    *a story with a nimble plot.*
>
> http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nimble

also want to include where I came across the weird word in the first place:
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=yare

Comment: I would never use *yare*. I'm not sure I've ever heard it, except maybe in pirate talk, about a ship.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever encountered ***yare***.

Comment: @Clare you raise a good point, but the piratey definition is below the nimble-like one

Comment: @JeffZeitlin granted yare is more obscure, but beyond that the definitions are so similar, and I hate to think that one synonym is preferred over another based solely on common usage and not the actual definition of the word

Comment: @chiliNUT the OED says about *yare*: "This word belongs in Frequency Band 3. **Band 3 contains words which occur between 0.01 and 0.1 times per million words in typical modern English usage**". So if people rarely ever hear it, it is not going to be recycled/reused much.

Comment: I've never seen "yare", just "yar", and I interpret it in the sailing sense, with other uses being figurative.  If you used "yare" to mean "nimble", most folks in the US would not know what you meant.

Comment: The OED also marks *yare* as archaic and dialectal. Not just one or two uses of it, but the word itself. Also, the latest usage it gives for yare(1) is "1869   Athenæum 28 Aug. 284/2   Yare, which is still current in Norfolk, and is pronounced yar, = brisk, active, lively." which, to me, implies it was  not still current in other places, and this from 1869.

Comment: The only definition the ODO gives is the ship one. ([link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/yare))

Comment: well, based on the comments it sounds like dictionary.com steered me wrong, such that any definition not pertaining to pirate ships is archaic

Comment: It's not really used in a non-archaic sense anymore.  But if you were to compare the definitions, as I see it, "yare" carries more of a connotation of *alertness* whereas "nimble" carries more of a connotation of being *light*

Comment: I’ve never seen that written and in 60 years of listening I’ve heard *yar* once, from Katharine Hepburn describing a yacht in *The Philadelphia Story* (1940). Some might recognise that better as the non-musical version of *High Society*.

In that movie it wasn’t wholly clear but yes, what she seemed to mean was very like *quick; agile; lively* and was specifically *of a ship*.

I *think* she went on to use *mighty yar* and I can't swear to that but either way, the difference seems to be that *yar* includes but is not limited to *nimble*.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between **yare** and **nimble** is that yare is obsolete and hardly ever used (except by Katherine Hepburn playing in *High-Society* 70 years ago), and nimble is a word in common use.  The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/231224?rskey=qwvnHa&result=2#eid)
has a lengthy entry with many examples, of which I list only three.

> 2. a. Alert, nimble, active, brisk, quick.
>
> 1698   J. Vanbrugh Short Vindic. 27   I believe, had the Obscenity he
>   has routed up here, been buried as deep in his Church-yard, the Yarest
>   Boar in his Parish wou'd hardly have tost up his Snout at it.
>
> 1707   E. Ward Wooden World Dissected 11   It's the Trick of a Hound
>   to be yare at Hares only.
>
> 1869   Athenæum 28 Aug. 284/2   Yare, which is still current in
>   Norfolk, and is pronounced yar, = brisk, active, lively.

Another definition of yare in the OED (same link) should really have added the Katherine Hepburn line, but instead chose to end its list of examples with a 1658 quotation.

> 2 b. Of a ship: Moving lightly and easily; answering readily to the
>   helm; easily manageable.
>
> 1658   Earl of Monmouth tr. P. Paruta Hist. Venice ii. iii. 177
>   Vluzzali..commanded 25 of his yarer gallies..to assault our right Wing

The OED (same link as above) also has a quotation from 1275, showing that **yare-witel** means quick witted.   Thus, yare, does indeed imply nimble as in the OP's definition #2 of nimble:

> 2.quick to understand, think, devise, etc.: a nimble mind

or it did in 1275.

I did not find a definition or a quotation in the OED for **yare** that means

> cleverly contrived (The OP's definition #3 of nimble.)